# Proof verification needed on exercise: a product of finitely many continuous functions $f_i:X\to\mathbb{R}$, $X$ compact and Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'm preparing for a qualifying exam in the fall, and I'm attempting the following exercise:

> Let $n\geq 1$ and
>   $$
> \big\{f_i\,:\,X\to\mathbb{R}\,|\,i=1,\ldots ,n\big\}
> $$
>   be a finite family of continuous functions such that, for each pair of distinct points $x,y\in X$, there exists $i,\,1\leq i\leq n$, with $f_i(x)\neq f_i(y)$. Show that $X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

I believe I have a proof (feel free to scroll past):

**My Attempt**

Let $F:X\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be the function given by
$$
F(x)=\big(f_1(x),\ldots , f_n(x)\big).
$$
Suppose that $F(x)=F(y)$. Then
$$
\big(f_1(x),\ldots , f_n(x)\big)=\big(f_1(y),\ldots , f_n(y)\big)
$$
and $f_i(x)=f_i(y)$ for each $i$. If $x\neq y$, this would directly contradict our assumption on the $f_i$, so $x=y$ and $F$ is injective, and hence bijective onto its image, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If $(p_1,\ldots, p_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set containing $p$, then via the product topology there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$
\Delta:=\underbrace{(p_1-\varepsilon, p_1+\varepsilon)\times\cdots\times(p_n-\varepsilon, p_n+\varepsilon)}_{n\text{-times}}\subset U,
$$
and since the $f_i$ are continuous, each $f_i^{-1}(p_i-\varepsilon,p_i+\varepsilon)$ is open in $X$. We claim that
$$
F^{-1}(\Delta)=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}f_i^{-1}(p_i-\varepsilon,p_i+\varepsilon).
$$
If $u\in F^{-1}(\Delta)$, then $|f_i(u)-p_i|<\varepsilon$ for all $i$ and the forward direction is proved (the former is a subset of the latter). If $v\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}f_i^{-1}(p_i-\varepsilon,p_i+\varepsilon)$, then $|f_i(v)-p_i|<\varepsilon$ for all $i$. Thus $v\in F^{-1}(\Delta)$ and the backward direction is proved (the latter is a subset of the former). Since $F^{-1}(\Delta)$ is an intersection of finitely many open sets, it is open, and hence $F$ is continuous

Lastly, any bijective and continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism, so we are done.

**Questions**

My concern is this: I don't believe I've used the hypothesis that $X$ was Hausdorff, which leads to me to believe I have made a mistake somewhere. This is a question from a previous qualifier (a timed exam) so maybe there were hypotheses added to make a proof easier and so less time consuming? Is this is a correct method of proof? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, and the hypothesis that $X$ is Hausdorff is not necessary.  Note that more generally your argument shows that if $f_i:X\to Y_i$ are continuous maps then the map $f:X\to\prod_i Y_i$ given by taking the $i$th coordinate of $f$ to be $f_i$ is continuous, for the product topology on $\prod_i Y_i$.

Comment: is this true for in general for infinite products of spaces? The proof I'm coming up with requires that it be a finite product.

Comment: @AlexMathers It holds for any product that $f$ is continuous iff $p_i \circ f$ is continuous for all projections $p_i$. This characterises the product topology. Your proof goes through, once you realise that basic open sets in the product essentially live on finitely many coordinates. And the existence of the $f_i$ shows $X$ must be Hausdorff (but we don't use it in the proof, it follows from it).